# Cancelling a report run on Reportserver for SSRS 2008?

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have users running various reports on the report manager website. There have been times when  I ask a user to cancel his/her report run on the report manager due to various reasons, at which point they'll go and close out the IE window where they were running the report. The problem is, even after they close out the window (or cancel the report), the RunningJobs table in the ReportServer database still shows that report as currently running.

Is there a way to kill these running jobs?

Any help/advise will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

N

Comment: I might suggest trying to fix whatever issue is causing you to have the user cancel the report, as opposed to making the report cancel more gracefully...

Answer (score 1):

You can manually cancel a report using the management studio, there are more details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156304.aspx.

It sounds like your reports are running for a long time. Are you able to look at the root cause of the long running report? Perhaps you need some indexes to improve performance?